# Refactoring gatsby-node File into separate files not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, gatsby, graphql-js

Trying to refactor my `gatsby-node` file, by outsourcing a bit of code. Right now trying to do this in my `gatsby-node`:

```
const createBlogPostPages = require("./gatsby-utils/createBlogPostPages");

exports.createPages = async ({ actions, graphql, reporter }) => {
  //...some code
  await createBlogPostPages({ actions, graphql, reporter });
  //...some code
}
```

and my `createBlogPostPages`, which is in a different file, looks like so:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = async function({ actions, graphql, reporter }) {
  const { createPage } = actions;

  const blogArticles = await graphql(`
    {
      allMdx(filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/content/blog/.*/" } }) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            fileAbsolutePath
            fields {
              slug
            }
            frontmatter {
              title
              tags
              date
              tagline
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  blogArticles.data.allMdx.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    let imageFileName = ... //some stuff

    createPage({
      path: `${node.fields.slug}`,
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`),
      context: {
        slug: `${node.fields.slug}`,
        id: node.id,
        imageFileName: imageFileName
      }
    });
  });
};
```

All of this works when its directly in `gatsby-node`. 
However, having moved stuff, I now get:

> "gatsby-node.js" threw an error while running the createPages
>   lifecycle:
>
> blogArticles is not defined
>
> ReferenceError: blogArticles is not defined
>
> - gatsby-node.js:177 Object.exports.createPages
>     /Users/kohlisch/blogproject/gatsby-node.js:177:19
> - next_tick.js:68 process._tickCallback
>     internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7

So it looks like it's not waiting for the graphql query to resolve? Or what might this be? I just basically want to move a few things out of my `gatsby-node` file, into separate functions, so that its not so cluttered. Is this not possible?

Answer (score 4):

There are two rules you need to follow when importing in `gatsby-node.js`:

### 1. Use node.js require syntax.

`./src/components/util/gatsby-node-functions`

```js
const importedFunction = () => {
  return Date.now();
};

module.exports.importedFunction = importedFunction;
```

`gatsby-node.js`

```js
const { importedFunction } = require(`./src/components/util/gatsby-node-functions`);

// ...
// Use your imported functions
console.log(importedFunction());
```

Reference: [Gatsby repo issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/7810), also incluces hack how to use ES6 import statement if you want to add complexity just for using an import statement.

### 2. Do not pass `gatsby-node.js` specific attributes to your imported functions

If you attempt to outsource for example, your createPages function, actions will be undefined:

```js
const importedFunction = (actions, node) => {
    const {createPage} = actions; // actions is undefined
    createPage({
      path: `${node.fields.slug}`,
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`),
      context: {
        slug: `${node.fields.slug}`,
        id: node.id,
      }
    });
};

module.exports.importedFunction = importedFunction;
```

Feel free to speculate why you cannot pass the attributes. The [Gatsby documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/actions/) mentions "Redux" for handling state. Maybe Redux does not supply state outside your `gatsby-node.js`. Correct me if I'm wrong